# JS hangs on a do while loop

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I can solve a hanging page with JS.

I have a JS loop which I'm testing like this, but it seems to hang forever - is there a way to stop it hanging while still completing the script ?:

```
<div id="my_data"></div>

<script>
function test(value){
output= [];
do{ 
    value++;
    output.push(value);
    document.getElementById('my_data').innerHTML = (output.join(''));
}while(value < 10000000);
alert('end'); // never occurs
}

test(0);
</script>
```

Comment: what you want to do with 10000000 times??

Comment: Nothing im just doing a test - i'm not applying it to a site or anything.

Comment: dont test the patience of a Browser

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov theres a timer before i can tick them.

Comment: @Dave in case you're interested, I've updated my answer to give you an idea what would work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating `10,000,000` consecutive numbers together into a string, which really will not work well on any modern supercomputer.

If you'd like to poll the progress, setup a timer to do it somewhat slower. It isn't practical, but it looks nice: http://jsfiddle.net/V6jjT/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="my_data"></div>
```

Script:

```
var value = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (value > 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    value++;
    document.getElementById('my_data').innerHTML += ' ' + value;
}, 10);
```

Comment: Can you update your question mentioning that you want to see the updates as they happen to make the question and answer more helpful to others?

Answer (score 7):

You're updating the DOM with an increasingly long string ten million times.

If you're some sort of super-being from the future, then maybe this makes sense.

Comment: How else can i do update the div as it loops so i can see the number go up ?

Comment: @Dave what in the world are you trying to do?

Comment: Just some testing with it but i want it to display "value" on the browser as it goes.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is single-threaded, so nothing else can happen while it's running your loop. It's running ten million times, and on each run it's setting the innerHTML of #my_data to something new. It's very inefficient and seems useless. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to see the number increase as it loops

Comment: This will not happen. The browser will only re-render after your loop is completed.

Comment: There must be a way to do it though.

Comment: Yes. If each iteration through the loop uses `setTimeout` to update the DOM, you might see some values popup sometimes.

Comment: @Dave: See the demo in my answer. The calculation you're trying to perform is going to override the rendering of the element, so the only solution is to have a timer update your value rapidly.

Answer (score 3):

Running a tight loop like that will not update anything until it's done; besides, 10M array items?!

If you really want to do this and not let the browser hang until forever you have to use `setInterval` to allow the browser to refresh in between.

```
function updater(value, max, interval) {
  var output = [],
  node = document.getElementById('my_data'),
  tid = setInterval(function() {
    if (value++ < max) {
      output.push(value);
      node.innerHTML = (output.join(''));
    } else {
      alert('done');
      clearInterval(tid);
    }
  }, interval);
}

updater(0, 10, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not update the HTML each iteration.

```
function test(value){
    output= [];
    do { 
        value++;
        output.push(value);
    } while(value < 10000000);
    document.getElementById('my_data').innerHTML = (output.join(''));
    alert('end'); // never occurs
}
```

should work (although 10 million numbers in a HTML will still need their time to render).

If you want to see numbers running, you should have a look at [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) - the browser needs some time between js execution to refresh its view. So, you will have to rewrite your code running several chunks of data asynchrously. See also:

- [Running a long operation in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196654/running-a-long-operation-in-javascript) (example code for your loop)
- [How can I force the browser to redraw while my script is doing some heavy processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209689/how-can-i-force-the-browser-to-redraw-while-my-script-is-doing-some-heavy-proces)
- [Javascript async loop processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9772400/1048572)
- [Prevent long running javascript from locking up browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/672732/1048572)
- [DOM refresh on long running function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17000032/1048572)
- [Best way to iterate over an array without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10344498/1048572)
- [Javascript - how to avoid blocking the browser while doing heavy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10180391/1048572)

Comment: But that will only result in showing the last number i want to see the number increase as it loops.

Comment: You can't really. The browser will update its UI to display the numbers when that loop is finished. Before it is hanging cause of the JS execution.

Answer (score 0):

Tight loop is likely to always exhaust computing power. I would do it in chunks. Say, divide your list into smaller lists and pause 5ms in between lists. I can provide an example if you need.