# Asynchronously remove children of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I have a `div#parent` element which has a few thousand sibling children `div#1`, `div#2`, `div#3` like so:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="1"> </div>
  <div id="2"> </div>  
  <div id="3"> </div>  
  …
  …
  …
  <div id="N"> </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to remove all children of the parent node -- preferably asynchronously or through a separate process?

Here are a few standard answers from the [wild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) that deal with slow and fast, but not async/e̶f̶f̶i̶c̶i̶e̶n̶t̶l̶y̶  or non-blocking:

**Option 1**:

```
var myNode = document.getElementById("foo");
myNode.innerHTML = '';
```

**Option 2**:

```
let parentNode = document.getElementById("parent");
while (parentNode.firstChild) {
    parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.firstChild);
}
```

Since a `while-loop` gives a "busy state" in the `dom`'s single threaded environment I wonder if there is a possibility to remove the nodes from the dom asynchronously/e̶̶̶f̶̶̶f̶̶̶i̶̶̶c̶̶̶i̶̶̶e̶̶̶n̶̶̶t̶̶̶l̶̶̶y̶  or in a non-blocking fashion?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid producing thousands of `div` tags in the first place?

Comment: Does `myNode.innerHTML = '';` not return expected result? What do you mean by "Asynchronously remove children"?

Comment: That's just the structure currently, it usually stays at a few hundred such elements, but can go up to a 1000 elements or so depending on the length of a write up.

Comment: @guest271314 meaning like on a web-worker (it doesn't have access to dom though) or in node environment or with promises().

Comment: What makes you think it needed to be asynchronous to be "efficient"?

Comment: @marvindanig _"meaning like on a web-worker "_ Not certain what you mean? Remove elements from `document` calling web worker within web worker? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: here are some async foreach loops, not sure how performant they are though https://h3manth.com/content/async-foreach-javascript

Comment: @bergi fixed to non-blocking instead of efficient. :-)

Comment: What is issue with using "Option 1" `.innerHTML = ""`? Is requirement to remove element one at a time?

Comment: @guest271314 it could be the straightforward answer, I'm just bouncing it off right now given newer patterns out there.

Comment: @marvindanig: You might want to have a look at [this list of links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10809905/1048572) about non-blocking loops

Comment: @marvindanig If requirement is not to remove elements one at a time `.innerHTML = ""` would return expected result; another pattern is not necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously `innerHTML = ''` will remove all items simultaneously. If this is too slow and you want to remove the elements little by little, then you need something similar to your second approach.

```
let parentNode = document.getElementById("parent");
(function remove() {
  // Remove elements in groups of 100
  for(let i=0; i<100 && parentNode.firstChild; ++i) {
    parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.firstChild);
  }
  // Continue asynchronously after 50ms
  setTimeout(remove, 50);
})();
```

Adjust the group size and the time delays as needed.